# How to combine 3 list together in a form like this {x,y,z}

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

have a list like this

```
list1={1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15}

list2={11.0528, 6.93761, 5.55466, 4.8553, 4.42977, 4.14146, 3.93179, 3.77147, 3.64418, 3.54016, 3.45315, 3.37899, 3.3148, 3.25849, 3.20856}

list3={16.9994, 13.6118, 19.826, 105.177, 21.7345, 55.8109, 130.38, 25.0771, 42.5648, 8.81212, 6.54, 5.789, 4.328, 9.658, 7.654}
```

I want to combine the three list into a form like this

```
list4={{1,11.0528,16.9994},{2,6.93761,13.6118},{3,5.55466,19.826}......}
```

One by one corresponding to each other

Is there a way to do so?

Comment: `Transpose[{list1,list2,list3}]`

Comment: @JasonB  Thanks it works, you should post something so I can give you the vote, otherwise I can not give you the vote

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Transpose[{list1, list2, list3}]
```

or

```
Thread[{list1, list2, list3}]
```

or a lot of other ways ...

Comment: `Flatten[{list1, list2, list3}, {{2}, {1}}]`